# Adjusting Application "Permissions" realtime

Tags: android

I know you can apply Permissions for Applications on its `manifest.xml` file. What I want to know is, can those Permissions be adjusted by the Applications on the fly?

Here's my reason: say I have an application that is allowed to do "x", "y", and "z" (SMS, sockets, etc) Permissions. Now let's say I have a logical "user" that connects to this Application, and I want that user to only be able to do "x" and "y", but not "z" Permissions. It would be nice to have the Android Framework handle that instead of having a bunch of "if's" in the App code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to know is, can those
>   Permissions be adjusted by the
>   Applications on the fly?

No, sorry.

Comment: Is it possible to reduce the Permissions? Meaning, The application has "x", "y", "z" Permissions, but I want to reduce the Permissions to "x" and "y" on the fly...can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

While it's not possible to change the Permissions that an App has, you can set your own permissions requirements on other applications connecting to yours.

See [Security and Permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html#declaring) in the Android Developer docs.

If your user is connecting from a separate client application, which then contacts your server application, you may be able to configure the permissions in the way you require. (I can't be certain without a bit more detail on the design that you are trying to implement).